# not able to connect to mongoDb from shell script

Tags: mongodb, windows, shell, mongoexport

Error - connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2022-04-11T17:21:32.757+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused

I have written a shell script program to export data of mongo DB into json file, I am able to execute commands from outside of shell script -  in terminal, but from shell script it says the above error. Using windows - powershell to run the script. Using same machine for running the script, individual commands when i run outside of shell files means in the Terminal executing well and giving result.

Code:
[image]

Comment: It'd be better to share source code instead of a screenshot. Could you also post the command you execute from cli (without script)?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
DB=$1
#-u the_username -p the_password --authenticationDatabase=admin
DB_COLLECTIONS=$(mongo $DB --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames().join(' ')" --host localhost --port 27017)
echo $DB_COLLECTIONS
for collection in $DB_COLLECTIONS; do
    echo "Exporting $DB/$collection ..."
    mongoexport --db=$DB --collection=$collection --out=$collection.json --host 127.0.0.1:27017
done

Comment: command used to run script - bash export-mongo-s3.sh user

Comment: Are you sure you use the same machine to run the line and the script? The code looks OK. In such weird case I usually try to make a simpler script, that prints current machine's name and available ports. Something like `ss -tulw` (it prints all local open connections)

Comment: Please edit your question for additional information instead of putting it as comment.